# Reverse scrolling in Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, google-chrome-os, chromebook

Is there a way that I can change my Chromebook's scrolling as OS X Lion's reverse scrolling? I both use Chromebook and MacBook Air. Reverse scrolling just makes sense.

Answer (score 24):

See [Use your Chromebook touchpad](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1047367) in the Chromebook Help.

Originally, the [Macify extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mdgchfpllcpbbemngpnealcmajkgbijb) also included a rough implementation of Apple's Natural Scrolling, Chrome OS now includes it out-of-the-box. To enable, just go to:

chrome://settings/pointer-overlay

and select Australian scrolling.

Answer (score 10):

Chrome OS natively supports inverted scrolling, look for it in Settings (dev channel only for now).

Comment: As of August 2012 it's in the stable channel. Settings > Touchpad settings > Enable simple scrolling direction

Comment: But unfortunately, that setting doesn't apply to external mice connected by USB (e.g. Logitech wireless mice), and Google seems unwilling to implement it. http://blog.orbeon.com/2013/11/adjusting-dropdown-width-on-ie7-and-ie8.html

Comment: It's called "Australian" scrolling in ChromeOS's touchpad settings.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Chrome's settings page (chrome://settings), under Device, click Touchpad settings, and select "Australian scrolling" instead of "Traditional scrolling".

See also [google's page on this topic](http://support.google.com/chromeos/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2583287), especially if Google updates Chrome OS to make the above advice outdated.